# Hide and unhide rows by clicking on a cell above (loop)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to excel VBA and I'm trying out some code to learn on my own using internet.

I'd like to hide/unhide rows by clicking the cell right above the hidden cells. Let's say :

```
Cell D6 - Project title 1
Cell D7 - First row of Project1 contents
.
.
.
.
Cell D26 - Last row of Project1 contents
Cell D27 - Project title 2
Cell D28 - First row of Project2 contents
.
.
.
.
Cell D47 - Last row of Project2 contents
```

I want to be able to hide/unhide row 7 to 26 by clicking on cell D6. And click D27 to hide/unhide row 28 to 47. I have 50 projects titles and contents on the same sheet.

I tried using worksheet selection change but my code doesn't work. Can anyone show me how to do it ?

Thank you !

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim A As Range
Dim B As Range

B = A.Rows + 1 & ":" & A.Rows + 20

If A = Target.Address Then

    Rows(B).EntireRow.Hidden = Not Rows(B).EntireRow.Hidden

End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to read up on some VBA basics. (1) You don't define `A`. (2) You declare `B` as a range but define it as a string.

Comment: Now you've removed your code and removed the formatting changes I made. Please reinstate.

Comment: I will read more, I've reinstated the correction you've made.

Comment: Thanks. Is it only those two ranges you want to hide/unhide or any range at all?

Comment: It's 50 repetitions of 1 row of Project titles and 20 rows of Project contents. So, I have 50 ranges of 20 rows to hide / unhide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to refine a bit, but this single line will do the bulk of it.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Target.Offset(1).Resize(20).EntireRow.Hidden = Not Target.Offset(1).Resize(20).EntireRow.Hidden

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will definitely read more to get better !